# Who came up with a formula expressing the sign function in terms of the absolute value?

Tags: mathematicians, notation

I read [here](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~tom/history/functions.html) and [here](http://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html) that Karl Weierstrass used "| |" to indicate absolute value in 1841. The same sources indicate that Leopold Kronecker wrote of the sign function in 1878. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) it is indicated that the sign function may be expressed via the absolute value function, $\textrm{sgn}(x)=\frac{x}{|x|}$, but no history of the practice is indicated. Any leads on who put them together if it wasn't Kronecker in 1878?

Comment: I don't really think there's any connection between the two other than that they deal with both positive and negative numbers.